# How to build custom dictionary from string lists faster

Tags: python, algorithm, set

## Background

I want to create dictionary that each word has an unique id for word embedding purpose. The dataset looks like:

```
s_lists = [['I', 'want', 'to', 'go', 'to', 'the', 'park'],
           ['I', 'want', 'to', 'quit', 'the', 'team']]
```

The following function is building a dictionary

```
def build_dict(input_list, start=2):
    """
    build dictionary
    start with 2，1 for unknow word，0 for zero padding

    :param input_list:
    :param start:
    :return: custom dictionary
    """

    whole_set = set()
    for current_sub_list in input_list:
         # remove duplicate elements
        current_set = set(current_sub_list)
        # add new element into whole set
        whole_set = whole_set | current_set
    return {ni: indi + start for indi, ni in enumerate(whole_set)}
```

It works and output

```
{'I': 7,'go': 2,'park': 4,'quit': 8, 'team': 6,'the': 5,'to': 9,'want': 3}
```

## Question

When I use it for a large dataset (around 50w strings), it will cost around **30s** (ENV mbpr15-i7). It is **too slow** and I want to search a solution to improve the performance but i have no idea at the moment.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code with [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain). In my test case it works about x4 faster:

```
from itertools import chain

start = 2
{it: n + start for n, it in enumerate(set(chain(*s_lists)))}
```

Comment: Awesome! it works for nearly x200 faster when feeding 50w dataset. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chain` and `count` from itertools

```
>>> from itertools import chain,count
>>> 
>>> dict(zip(set(chain(*s_lists)), count(2)))
{'team': 2, 'park': 3, 'want': 4, 'I': 5, 'the': 6, 'quit': 7, 'to': 8, 'go': 9}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
flatern_s_lists = [item for sub_item in s_lists for item in sub_item]
result = {j:i+2 for i,j in enumerate(set(flatern_s_lists))}
```

Making a list of lists to flatter this the best option in case of the speed of execution.

Result:

```
{'quit': 2, 'I': 3, 'park': 4, 'to': 5, 'want': 6, 'team': 7, 'go': 8, 'the': 9}
```

Comment: Yeah!, much better than mine but just a little bit slower than @Kopytok 's solution. More precisely it costs 0.2474s compared to 0.1053s (50w data). It's simple enough to understand by the way :)